# Find mass of CO₂ and heat released per minute in a combustion reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, combustion

I am not sure where to start with this problem. I know that $\small q = mc(T_f-T_i)$, but that seems like it would not help here. I think I need to balance the equation, but I am not sure how the rate factors into the problem. Anyway, if anyone could help me find the relevant equations/method for solving this problem, it would be greatly appreciated:

A natural gas mixture is burned in a furnace at a power-generating station at a rate of 13.0 mol per minute.

1. If the fuel consists of 9.3 mole $\small\ce{CH4}$, 3.1 mole $\small\ce{C2H6}$, 0.40 mol $\small\ce{C3H8}$, and 0.20 mole $\small\ce{C4H10}$, what mass of $\small\ce{CO2} (g)$ is produced per minute?
2. How much heat is released per minute?

Comment: I think it's safe to treat each of those reactions separately (so CH4 will reaction with O2 to form CO2 and H2O without being affected by C2H6, which will itself react with O2, etc.).  In terms of heat released, you probably have a table of enthalpies (deltaH) of formation for each of those reactions in a table or something.

Answer (score 5):

You know the amounts of the four gases burned in a minute.  Just write combustion reactions for each of these and work out the heat produced by each reaction **as written**. That's your answer to the second part.  Adding up the carbon dioxide produced in each of the four combustion reactions is the answer to the first part.